# Streaming Push Topics - Could not load Push Topics

Tags: platform-event, workbench, streaming-api, pushtopic, system-admin

My colleagues and I are unable to get into the workbench page https://workbench.developerforce.com/streaming.php as we get the following error:

[image]

I've checked the workbench code and all it does is to check that the running user has permissions to SOQL the PushTopics. We're System Administrators and I've double-checked that the SOQL returns records for us.

The ORG has both the "REST API" and "Streaming API" enabled.

Any idea what can it be?

For the record, the error message is "Could not load Push Topics. Ensure the both the REST and Streaming APIs are enabled for this organization." and it can be found in the line 58 of the StreamingController.php file (https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench/blob/main/workbench/controllers/StreamingController.php)

Comment: Workbench is not officially supported by Salesforce. Streaming API subscription with Workbench is sometimes flaky and salesforce no longer recommends using Workbench. Can you use the [EMP Connector](https://github.com/forcedotcom/EMP-Connector)  and see if the issue still persists. [Example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/code_sample_java_client_intro.htm)

Comment: Additionally, I have seen a similar issue in past wherein enabling the [Edge Network](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000350511&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1) fixed this error in workbench. Recommend testing in the sandbox first.

Comment: Thanks @Swetha, using EMP Connector works flawlessly but it's much less friendly. 

Edge Network is enabled too, btw.

I know it's not supported by Salesforce so that's why I went here instead of creating a ticket there :)

If there's someone else that knows or can help I would appreciate, otherwise I'll mark your answer as the good one

Comment: Thanks for confirming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing posted comment:

Workbench is not officially supported by Salesforce. Streaming API subscription with Workbench is sometimes flaky and salesforce no longer recommends using Workbench.

The recommendation is to use the [EMP Connector](http://github.com/forcedotcom/EMP-Connector), which is a Java client tool and also open-source to fix the issue. See example [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/code_sample_java_client_intro.htm)

In few scenarios, enabling the [Edge Network](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000350511&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1) does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Today another solution is available on Google Chrome: [Maven Tools](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/maven-tools-for-salesforc/kgookdjjmmekebgdecakmblghjgiaoem) is a Chrome Plugin for Salesforce which offers very nice features like an intelligent query editor, REST console, event hub and many more, giving you the power to deliver changes more quickly and effectively.
To view the Streaming Push topics, navigate to Event Hub the select 'Push Topics' from the first list, Select the desire Push Topic and click Subscribe.
[image]